# According to whether the package exists in the window or not load the package dynamically

Tags: javascript, webpack

Does any build tool support this loading strategy, such as webpack or rollup.js.

Build every dependency to a single bundle, and when loading these dependencies, firstly search it in window['package'], if exist, use it. Otherwise dynamic load dependencies bundle to use.

Such app dependency is React, ReactDOM and UiLib.

The built result is:

```markdown
React -> a.js
ReactDOM -> b.js
UiLib -> c.js
my code -> d.js
```

if window.React exist but window.ReactDOM and window.UiLib does not exist. d.js should dynamically load b.js and c.js and use window.React.

I know I can config React to externals, but this is a microapp used in many different apps, I'm not sure which packages exist in every global.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. It is not possible directly. For a bundler, it is a binary choice between bundle or not to bundle.

Why? When a bundler encounters a library via import statements like - `import React from 'react'`, it needs to know what global object it should substitute whenever it encounters `react` package across the entire application dependency graph. This must happen at compile-time. Additionally, loading a library with dynamic decision at runtime means you are introducing an **asynchronous** behavior in your code which your components or application cannot handle readily.

There are two form factors - a library and application. As far as library is considered, this is the only way to teach bundler (either bundle it or leave it via `externals`).

At an application level, you can write your own code to partially achieve what you seek with help of CDN. For this, you use externals and tell Webpack, for example, that `react` will be available as global `React` object on `window` namespace.

Now before your library is getting consumed, you have to add a dynamic code where to check for presence of `React` object.

```js
function async initialize() {
  if (!window.React) {
    const React = await import(/* webpackIgnore: true */ 'https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js')
    window.React = React;

    initializeMicroapp();
  } else {
    initializeMicroapp();
    return Promise.resolve();
  }
}
```

Your `initialize` function for microapp is async and returns a promise. This is usually the pattern to go ahead with **shell + micro-frontends**.

> On a side note, you can use **module federation** approach which is actually meant to solve exactly similar use-case. With module federation, you can teach Webpack that if the host/shell provides a library, then Webpack should simply ignore its bundled copy of that library while serving only other necessary code. However, I advice caution as it is a very specific pattern and neither de-facto nor de-jure at this point. It is recommended when you are having sufficient scale and many independent teams working on same product space.

Comment: So, What I need is a loader, that can preload packages first. Thank you so much, I'll get it a try.